# How to display the message after 10 min of logging-in in progress4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

How to display the message after 10 min of logging-in in progress4GL

A user can be logged in for a maximum of 10 minutes in the session. A warning message should
be displayed after 9 minutes of logging in .

Comment: can you share, more details about your stuff please

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ETIME to calculate the time after logging in (just remember that this is in milliseconds)...

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P55318

```
DEFINE VARIABLE timer AS INT64 NO-UNDO.

    timer = ETIME(yes).

    WHEN timer > 600000 THEN DO:
        //code

    END.
```